# Getting 403 error on init call for web messenger from smooch.io

Tags: smooch

Web messenger stopped working pre Version 4, changed init, see below:

```
Smooch.init({
    appId : '<my appID>',
    embedded: true
}).then(() => {
    Smooch.sendMessage("Hello Bank Assist")
    Smooch.render(document.getElementById('watson'))
});
```

and getting http error 403, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3 of the Web Messenger was deprecated in Summer 2017, and support was officially discontinued in early July 2018. You'll need to update to a version > 4.0.0 in order to keep using your integration. Installation instructions can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/#installation). See the [v4.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web/releases/tag/4.0.0) for notable changes when switching from the 3.x version series.

There was a change to embedded mode that you'll need to account for in your init code. In embedded mode, you now need to call `render` in order for the `init` logic to start, so your code should look like this instead:

```
Smooch.init({
    appId : '<my appID>',
    embedded: true
}).then(() => {
    Smooch.sendMessage("Hello Bank Assist");
});
Smooch.render(document.getElementById('watson'));
```